# Segmentation fault, while comparing the two values one from array and one from stack?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, stack

context: After checking whether the entered expression is correct or not, I'm passing that array to the infix2postfix function.

here while comparing the precedence of operators,
`while (iprec(a[i]) < sprec(top->ch ))`
it showed the segmentation fault, so then I tried to add if(top!=NULL) condition before while loop, and it worked, but when i changed the condition to
`while (iprec(a[i]) <= sprec(top->ch ))`
it again gives the segmentation fault.

Questions :
1.What should I do to resolve it?

```
void infix2postpix(char a[])
{
    char pfix[strlen(a)];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (Isopd(a[i]))
        {
            pfix[k++] = a[i];
        }

        else if (((Isopr(a[i])) || a[i] == '(' || a[i] == '{' || a[i] == '['))
        {
           
            
                while (iprec(a[i]) < sprec(top->ch ))

                {
                    
                        pfix[k++] = pop();
                    
                }
            
            push(a[i]);
        }

        if (a[i] == ')' || a[i] == '[' || a[i] == '{')
        {
            char c;
            while ((c = pop()) != '(' && top != NULL)
            {
                pfix[k++] = c;
                c = pop();
            }
        }
    }
    while (top != NULL)
    {
        pfix[k++] = pop();
    }
    pfix[k] = '\0';
    printf("%s", pfix);
}
```

Q: 2  Why is it necessary to check if the top is equal to NULL or not in pop() function, it depends on the user :
case 1: when a user tries to pop an element and there isn't any element to pop then only it should show the segmentation fault.
case 2 : When a user pushes something first all the time and then performs the pop then it should work properly. But why during compilation it give a segmentation fault every time?

```
int pop()
{
    if (top == NULL)
    {
        printf("Underflow of stack, cannot perform pop operation\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        index--;
        int item;
        st *temp;
        temp = top;
        item = top->no; // or temp->no
        top = top->prev;
        free(temp);
        return item;
    }
}
```

sorry if second question sounds silly, thank you for reading.

Comment: Start by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to catch the crash, and examine all variables at the time and location (in *your* code) of the crash.

Comment: Also remember that `strlen` does *not* include the string null terminator in its length. Think about that when you do `char pfix[strlen(a)];`

Comment: `pfix[k] = '\0';` looks risky because of [`char pfix[strlen(a)];`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77182195/segmentation-fault-while-comparing-the-two-values-one-from-array-and-one-from-s#comment136065055_77182195).

Comment: "But why during compilation it give a segmentation fault every time?" is unclear.  "segmentation fault" is a run-time issue, not really ever a _compilation_ one.

Comment: *"second question"*: a question should be *one* question. Please focus your question on that.

Comment: Hint: format your code properly. Unreadable code is hard to debug.